# Setting up Apache

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm setting up Apache server for elgg (an open source social networking framework) . I've installed apache2 on ubuntu and created a new  file 'elgg' on 'sites-available' folder in /etc/apache2/ , copying the contents of default file already in that folder .I also  changed the document root and directory setting inside the file and made no other changes .I enabled the site using a2ensite .  But when i try to access the site through the browser it says -  403 forbidden , You cannot access this diectory . Is there something i did wrong ?  I gave all users read ,write and exec permission in document root folder , still it's shown as forbidden

Answer (score 0):

- Check if one of the files specified as 'DirectoryIndex' is available and accessible, or if 'Indexes' is as Option.
- Check for .htaccess files with possible 'Deny' conditions, or a Deny condition in your 'elgg' file in sites-available.

(Edit: removed 1, was already done)

Comment: DirectoryIndex is available and i've set to index.php . There're no .htaccess files in my server , so i assume it's not configured